# Instancia do axios não retorna no export do nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

Estou tentando retornar a instancia criada através do axios pelo `module.exports`,
porém quando tento usa-lá me da esse erro:

> http(...).get is not a function

***Meu arquivo http-common.js***

```
var axios = require('axios');

var instancia = axios.create({
    baseURL: `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/`,
});

module.exports = instancia;
```

***Meu index.js***

```
var http = require('./app/infraestrutura/http-common')();
http.get('/users')
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response)
        }).
        catch(function(err){
            console.log(response)
        })
```

Comment: Remova os parenteses do require em `require('./app/infraestrutura/http-common')()`. Deveria ser `require('./app/infraestrutura/http-common')`

Comment: @user140828 funcionou, porém não como eu queria, a ideia era ele só executar o `request`, quando eu chamasse o método `.get()` ou `.post()`

Comment: Mas isso é exatamente o que está acontecendo. Como você chama o método `get` imediatamente após importar o módulo, ele faz a requisição logo de cara. Se você queria chamar essa requisição mais tarde, talvez seja o caso de coloca-la dentro de uma função e chamar essa função somente quando necessário.

Comment: @user140828 é você tem razão, a melhor forma de fazer isso é exportar a própria instância do axios e setar a `baseURL` ( através do axios.defaults )  antes de exporta-lá

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solução foi exportar o própria instancia do axios por inteiro, e fazer a modificações antes de exporta-lo:

```
var axios = require('axios');
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/';

module.exports = axios;
```